# make: disable parallel execution of some targets

Tags: makefile, parallel-processing

I have a compile job where linking is taking a lot of IO work. We have around a dozen of cores so we run make -j13, but when it comes to linking the 6 targets, I'd like those to be done in a round robin way. I thought about making one depend on the next but I think this would break the individual targets. Any ideas how to solve this small issue?

Comment: How could that "break individual targets"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`make` itself doesn't provide a mechanism to request "N of these, but no more than M of those at a time".

You might try using the `sem` command from the [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/) package in the recipe of your linker rules. Its documentation has an [example of ensuring only one instance of a tool runs at once](https://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/sem.html#example__protecting_pod2html_from_itself). In your example, you would allow `make` to start up to 13 `sem`s at a time, but only one of those at a time will run the linker, while the others block.

The downside is that you could get into a situation where 5 of your `make`'s 13 job slots are tied up with instances of `sem` that are all waiting for a linker process to finish. Depending on the structure of your build, that might mean some wasted CPU time. Still beats 6 linkers thrashing the disk at once, though :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should specify that your six targets cannot be built in parallel. Add a line like this to your makefile:

```
.NOTPARALLEL: target1 target2 target3 target4 target5 target6
```

For more information look here https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Disable.html.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon a hacky solution:

For each recipe it runs, Make does two things: it expands variables/functions in the recipe, and then runs the shell commands.

Since the first step can read/write the global variables, it seems to be done synchronously.

So if you run all your shell commands during the first step (using `$(shell` `)`), no other recipe will be able to start while they're running.

E.g. consider this makefile:

```
all: a b

a:
        sleep 1

b:
        sleep 1
```

`time make -j2` reports 1 second.

But if you rewrite it to this:

```
# A string of all single-letter Make flags, without spaces.
override single_letter_makeflags = $(filter-out -%,$(firstword $(MAKEFLAGS)))

ifneq ($(findstring n,$(single_letter_makeflags)),)
# See below.
override safe_shell = $(info Would run shell command: $1)
else ifeq ($(filter --trace,$(MAKEFLAGS)),)
# Same as `$(shell ...)`, but triggers a error on failure.
override safe_shell = $(shell $1)$(if $(filter-out 0,$(.SHELLSTATUS)),$(error Unable to execute `$1`, exit code $(.SHELLSTATUS)))
else
# Same functions but with logging.
override safe_shell = $(info Shell command: $1)$(shell $1)$(if $(filter-out 0,$(.SHELLSTATUS)),$(error Unable to execute `$1`, exit code $(>
endif

# Same as `safe_shell`, but discards the output and expands to nothing.
override safe_shell_exec = $(call,$(call safe_shell,$1))


all: a b

a:
        $(call safe_shell_exec,sleep 1)
        @true

b:
        $(call safe_shell_exec,sleep 1)
        @true
```

`time make -j2` now reports 2 seconds.

Here, `@true` does nothing, and suppresses `Nothing to be done for ??` output.

There are some problems with this approach though. One is that all output is discarded unless redirected to file or `stderr`...

Comment: How about controlling parallel execution with make directives `.NOTPARALLEL`, and `.WAIT `. https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parallel-Disable.html

Comment: @nobody Looks promising, consider posting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

It won't break individual targets.
You can create any number of (`:`) rules for a target, as long as only one of them has an actual recipe for building it.  This appears to be a good use case for that.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I tried | dependency-order   but it doesn't work as intended since it builds de dependencies even when compiling a single target.

Comment: Can you be more specific as well?  What exactly did you try?